# Caching JNDI Lookup

Tags: java, ejb, jndi

Recommended way of invoking a EJB local interface method is to perform a lookup:

```
<code>
Context ic = new IntialContext(); 
ic.lookup(objectJndiName);
</code>
```

However, I browse the complete JNDI tree at the start of application and at the end I am able to create a map of all objects with:

```
<code> 
   Map <String,Object> 
</code>
```

with key ObjectName and object of required Interface Implementation. I search the object with key and invoke the required method on interface like this:

```
method.invoke(bean, args);
```

Is this method ok? or should I perform lookup for the required ejb everytime?

Comment: Your way won't catch changes that occur after you load your Map. There no point to this. There is nothing expensive being optimized here.

Comment: I do not need to track changes in impl object as implementations are stateless session beans with methods without needing any state.

Comment: I didn't say anything about changes to impl objects. I just said changes. Don't jump to conclusions. There could be changed in what is bound. There is still no point to this. So don't do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JNDI lookups is not the recommended way for instantiating references of Local Interfaces of Stateless beans, as from EE5 and above.  Simply injecting the bean with @EJB annotation or CDI's @Inject will do the job fine.

Comment: Its a legacy code problem. Using annotations is not an option in current scenario. Existing code is with hard coded naming conventions to resolve impl classes. This is first step. next step is naturally activating EJB and Inject annotations. Do you see any issues with Thread safety?

Comment: Sorry but you have mentioned local interface. I think that in the EJB 2.x there were Home and Remote interfaces not local ones. Haven't used them since long time ago and I can only recall the use of the 'Service Locator' EE Pattern in which JNDI obtained references are been cached inside a singleton class.

Comment: Local interfaces were introduced in the EJB 2.1 specification